# Цикличное обновление данных

Tags: android, kotlin, файловая-система, viewmodel

Получаю данные с термодатчиков устройсва. Как будет правильнее реализовать циклический опрос датчиков, для примера с интервалом у 5 сек? Данные считываю с `sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`. Присвоение модели:

```
val temperatureCPU : Int = TempInfoUtils().getTemperature(TempInfoUtils.CPU_TEMP_FIRST_ZONE_PATH)
val temperatureGPU : Int = TempInfoUtils().getTemperature(TempInfoUtils.GPU_TEMP_PATH)
val temperatureBattery : Int = TempInfoUtils().getTemperature(TempInfoUtils.BATTERY_TEMP_PATH)
val temperatureWiFi : Int = TempInfoUtils().getTemperature(TempInfoUtils.WI_FI_TEMP_PATH)

val temperature = Temperature()
    temperature.cpuTemp = temperatureCPU
    temperature.gpuTemp = temperatureGPU
    temperature.batteryTemp = temperatureBattery
    temperature.wifiTemp = temperatureWiFi

    binding.viewModel?.temperature = temperature
```

Comment: WorkManager поможет: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: И что-то у вас не то с использованием `TempInfoUtils`, зачем 4 раза объект создавать?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, за TempInfoUtils спасибо, все методы уже статические.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, похоже с WorkManager не выйдет. Класс PeriodicWorkRequest дает возможность выполнять задачу не больше 1 раза в 15 минут. Нужно хотя бы не больше 10 сек.